# Is there a way to buy food in bulk cheap in Germany?

Tags: germany

Is there any cheaper way to buy food in bulk in Germany than at the supermarket? Could you somehow get, say, 60-100 eggs, or 10 liters of milk, for cheaper?

Comment: Prices vary. How cheap do you want milk to be? A liter costs between 60 ct and 1,90 EUR according to store and quality (fresh, durable, how the cows are bread etc.)

Comment: I feel this question does not really fit our format. Does any of our users know a better SE site to move it to?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic

Comment: These amounts can rarely be considered bulk amounts. Cartons with 12l milk or trays with 30 eggs are sizes sold in regular super markets.

Comment: This has nothing to do with travel. The same question could be asked by a long-term resident. VTC.

Comment: Yeah, they're called restaurant supply stores.

Answer (score 2):

Buying in bulk in Germany screams for METRO. [Here](https://www.metro.de/standorte)'s a list of locations. You can easily get things like 10kg blocks of cheese.

Caveats:

- It's not necessarily cheaper than discounter supermarkets when calculating the price per kg. But their package sizes are much more convenient if you cook for 50+ people.
- You need to be a "Gewerbetreibender" (own a business) or be a registered association (like a sports club) to get access. Though I know a few people that meet neither criterion themselves and still shop there. All you need is to know someone who does and who can give you a temporary pass.

Comment: If METRO is like the Macro in the Netherlands, you will be better off when you go to the cheaper supermarkets or even buy the cheaper brands and the special offers in all supermarkets. Do not forget to add the tax, as often these shops for business owners do not show them in the big text prices.